# nuget.exe ignores inheritance for packageSourceCredentials

Tags: nuget

Is it possible to configure Nuget so the package sources are configured in the `nuget.config` file in the solution dir, while the credentials for those sources are configured in the `nuget.config` file located at the user level (`%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`)?

Reading [how settings are applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) for nuget operations, seems like `nuget.config` has some sort of inheritance. I was trying to use this inheritance to configure nuget for my team in the following way.

1. Each developer will have a personal set of credentials to the Nuget repository.
2. Each visual studio solution will contain a `Nuget.config` file in the solution directory.

   2.1. The `Nuget.config` file will contain two package sources: nuget.org, and a private credential required source.
3. Each developer will configure the credentials to the private Nuget source within the file located in the user profile (`%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`). In this way, those credentials are not committed to source control.

here are some examples of the `nuget.config` files I am trying to use:

Solution level file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="Private" value="url_for_the_private_feed" />
    </packageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>  
</configuration>
```

User level file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />    
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Private>
      <add key="Username" value="user_name_here" />
      <add key="Password" value="encrypted_password_here" />
    </Private>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

For some reason, I am not able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that if the NuGet command includes the argument `-configFile <path to nuget.config>` then the behavior described in [how settings are applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) does not apply, and instead, the NuGet CLI will only consider the configuration file passed as a parameter.

This is not clear in the documentation. For some reason, I thought that I could pass a `nuget.config` file to the NuGet CLI, and it would use that file in conjunction with the user-level configuration and the computer-level configuration.

Comment: The online documentation appears to be incorrect, and contradicts the in-app help, e.g. `nuget restore -?`. This has been reported and acknowledged: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11836